# How to show confirm dialog before page reload on iOS using javascript in 2016?

Tags: javascript, ios, page-refresh, onbeforeunload

Could anyone explain me how to show confirm dialog on page refresh on iOS devices?

We use window.onbeforeunload handler on desktop, it works fine and as we expect. But the problem was found when we tried to check hot it works on iOS devices.

I found a lot of information here about pagehide and unload events, and that they work fine on iOS devices, but all my attempts was failed.

Please, help me and provide working code example. (I'm testing app on iPad Air 2, iOS 9.3.2).